# print file name with number of forms

Tags: jquery

I have number of forms on a page and each one has a file input. When the user chooses a file, I would like to print the name of the selected file in the `<span class="fileNameBox"></span>` that is inside the relevant form.

Why does it always print the file's name in the first form / class="fileNameBox"
?

JS:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('input.file-field').on('change', function(e) {
        var files = this.files,
            filename = files[0].name;
        $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html(filename);
      });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="form-control comment-field" name="comment[text]" rows="1" ></textarea>
            <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
            <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="uploadFile"/>
        </div>

        <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label" for="uploadFile">
            <img src="images/photoIconOn.png" alt="" class="uploadFileImg"/>
        </label>
    </div>                      
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="textinput"></label>  
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary submit" >SEND</button>
        </div>
    </div>                                      
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="form-control comment-field" name="comment[text]" rows="1" ></textarea>
            <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
            <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="uploadFile"/>
        </div>

        <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label" for="uploadFile">
            <img src="images/photoIconOn.png" alt="" class="uploadFileImg"/>
        </label>
    </div>                      
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="textinput"></label>  
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary submit" >SEND</button>
        </div>
    </div>                                      
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand `in the that is` can you clearify your question with that part? to respond why does it print the filename in the first class that is because this line `$(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html(filename);` doing exactly that. what is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: I can't see what you're talking about... http://www.bootply.com/7ifK5Dcig7 If I upload a file called `image.png` to the first one, it appears above the first one. If I upload `image_2.png` to the second one, it appears above the second one.

Comment: Your code is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/uf8Lojzo/